# Querying MySQL with PHP and javascript drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I've looked all over for a few days now, but haven't found a solution to my problem.  I'm writing some PHP to query from a MySQL database that I have setup on my WAMP server. I'm also learning PHP and HTML javascript as I go, so the syntax of both languages is still a little unfamiliar to me.

My goal is to have a drop down selector box is written in Java that allows the user to chose a filter to apply to the select query, something like this:

```
SELECT * from exampletable WHERE header = "selected_option"
```

Where 'exampletable' is the table existing in the SQL database, 'header' is a column within that table, and 'selected option' is the user's choice from the drop-down.

I have tried writing various HTML forms with actions that call the PHP file that contains the SQL query using the `$_POST` superglobal, but nothing seems to work.  Any suggestions and examples of solutions would be amazing.

Thanks!

index.php (index.php is the front end with the user interface)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
    <select name="family">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Any family</option>
                <option value="capacitory">capacitor</option>
                <option value="resistor">resistor</option>
                <option value="ferrite bead">ferrite bead</option>
    </select>
    <input name="search" type="submit" value="Search>
</form>
</html>
```

search.php (search.php receives the selected option value and passes it into the MySQL query)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','kelly188','mysql');
mysqli_select_db($con,"testv2");

$varfam = $_POST['family'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE (family = $varfam)";

$result = mysqli_query($query);

if($result)
{
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row['family']."</td>";
}
} else {
die(mysqli_error());
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: You have provided too little code for us to go on to help where you are specifically stuck. Otherwise, this would be a very broad question, and off-topic.

Comment: I will edit my post to display what I have

Comment: "but nothing seems to work"  What exactly did you try?  What was the expected/desired result?  What was the actual result?  If you got errors, what were the exact errors?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: well for starters $result = mysqli_query($query); needs 2 params the first being the connection then you have to get the results what  you have done will only output the query not the results of said query -- edit: sorry i just saw you are using results ignore last part

Comment: Also, you're mixing `mysqli_` and the deprecated/removed `mysql_` functions.  Further, you should look into using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to fix the fact that your text values need to be quoted in the query.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.php

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<select name="family">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Any family</option>
            <option value="capacitory">capacitor</option>
            <option value="resistor">resistor</option>
            <option value="ferrite bead">ferrite bead</option>
</select>
<input name="search" type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

search.php

```
<?php
//////////////////////////////////
// Connect to database using PDO
$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "test";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test_db";
$db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,$password);
// End of database connection
////////////////////////////////////

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$family = $_POST['family'];
if(empty($_POST['family']))
{
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM testv2");
$stmt->execute();
//we get the data
while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo $data['family'];
echo "<hr>";    
}   
}
else
{   
$stmt = $db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family = :family");
$stmt ->bindParam(':family', $family);
$stmt->execute();
//we get the data
while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
echo $data['family'];
echo "<hr>";    
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, I have tried implementing it with my database info.  I believe the connection works, but I'm simply not seeing any results from selecting one of the options in the drop down.  I do apologize if I'm being obtuse and missing something fundamental.

Comment: else, make sure   the word inside $data[''];  (in this case it's family) is a valid column name from the table testv2

Comment: family is indeed a valid column.  However when I try and execute the code, my webpage seems to run for a while and then comes up blank.  It seems like the table is created but is not displayed, might that be the case?  EDIT: I'm realizing now that I didn't make it clear in my original post that I wanted to display the results of the query.  How might I go about doing that?  And thanks for all of your help!

Comment: That's exactly what the code does, displaying all related "family" upon selection and submission, any other details or screenshot of the db ? maybe i'm missing something.   you can add : $rows = $stmt->rowCount(); below     $stmt->execute(); and then : echo $rows; this would return the number of related rows, we may get something out of this

Comment: I just added a picture of the db table to my original post, let me know if you need anything else.  Your suggestion about adding rows seem reasonable

Comment: Well, index.php runs well as far as I can tell.  It calls search.php once I entered the valid server credentials, but nothing is displayed once the page is called.

Comment: That's strange, you're sure the table name is testv2 as well ? it should at least display all data from that table if it's not getting the $_POST['family'] input

Comment: Unfortunately nothing is displaying, the table name is testv2.  I'm sorry I can't be of very much use for debugging as I'm just learning the language, I appreciate the effort but don't worry if you can't figure it out.

Comment: We're all learning my brother, i just created the same exact table (with random values) and it's working perfectly ! you can use the edited search.php, just make sure you're using the right database connection details. IT'll works hopefully :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection. The mysql_fetch_array function has been removed from recent versions of PHP. Something more like the following would be more ideal.

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE (family = ?)")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s",  $_POST['family']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".htmlentities($row['family'])."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }   

    $stmt->close();
}
```

See PHP documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Much better advice than simply saying to put quotes around a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I really don't think I need to be concerned about injection however, as my script will never be run on a server with public access and the MySQL databse I'm querying from doesn't contain any sensitive information.  I'm storing inventory information that can be found on a number of websites